# Angular 2 - App Module declaration of Upgraded AngularJS component not working

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/itsphil/b0460a57daf2b8522b7644a5b48a9d72)

I have an application running AngularJS and Angular side by side, using the `UpgradeModule`. I have "upgraded" and AngularJS component (`angular.component`) for use in our Angular components (`@Component`). I have done so using the instructions on the Angular 1.x upgrade page.

The issue is that when this "upgraded" component is declared in the AppModule `declarations: []` array, I receive an error saying `unknown element 'tooltip'`.

When I remove the declaration from the AppModule and declare it instead in the `@NgModule` for the component in which the upgraded component will be used, it works fine.

Please review the Gist for the code that is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the behavior.

- The components must be declared in the module where you want to use it.
- If you want to use the component in multiple modules, Create a `SharedModule` (shared module) and add your component to it's `declarations` and `exports`.
- Import the `SharedModule` in other modules wherever you want to use this component.

More about shared modules in [Angular2 Docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#shared-module).

And here is a [nice tutorial](http://blog.angular-university.io/angular2-ngmodule/) on `NgModules` that might help you.